# ZeroMQ pyzmq send jpeg image over tcp

Tags: image, jpeg, zeromq, pyzmq

I am trying to send a jpeg image file through a ZeroMQ connection with pyzmq, but the output is 3 times the size of the input, and no longer a valid jpeg.  I load the image and send with...

```
f = open("test1.jpg",'rb')
strng = f.read()
socket.send(strng)
f.close()
```

I receive and save with...

```
message = socket.recv()
f = open("test2.jpg", 'w')
f.write(str(message))
f.close()
```

I am new to zmq, and I could not find any info on sending images.  Has anyone sent images through ZeroMQ, or have any ideas on how to find the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before sending the file you can "base64" encode it and decode it when received.

Sending:

```
import base64
f = open("test1.jpg",'rb')
bytes = bytearray(f.read())
strng = base64.b64encode(bytes)
socket.send(strng)
f.close()
```

Receiving:

```
import base64
message = socket.recv()
f = open("test2.jpg", 'wb')
ba = bytearray(base64.b64decode(message))
f.write(ba)
f.close()
```

Comment: you can convert bytearray to bytes directly. base64 is a little slower.

Comment: wow you can just send big file in 1 message?  can you explain what op did wrong that you fixed?

Answer (score 2):

You can try [imagezmq](https://github.com/jeffbass/imagezmq). It's specially built for transporting images using PyZMQ messaging.

**Sender**

```
import socket
import imagezmq

sender = imagezmq.ImageSender(connect_to='tcp://receiver_name:5555')

sender_name = socket.gethostname() # send your hostname with each image

image = open("test1.jpg",'rb')
sender.send_image(sender_name, image)
```

**Receiver**

```py
import imagezmq

image_hub = imagezmq.ImageHub()

sender_name, image = image_hub.recv_image()
image_hub.send_reply(b'OK')
```

Answer (score 0):

**Zero-copy string manipulations on C-strings**

( from [enter link description here](http://zeromq.github.io/pyzmq/pyversions.html#bytes-and-strings) )

**Bytes and Strings**
Note
If you are using Python >= 2.6, to prepare your PyZMQ code for Python3 you should use the **`b'message'`** syntax to ensure all your string literal messages will still be bytes after you make the upgrade.

The most cumbersome part of PyZMQ compatibility from a user’s perspective is the fact that, since ØMQ uses C-strings, and would like to do so without copying, we must use the Py3k bytes object